# Stripe customers export not consist of billing address

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have created a sample stripe application with stripe elements. It captures the card number and cvc. But not the card holder address. So I have created html fields for address and include them while creating customer object. But it is not showing the address details when I export data from stripe dashboard. If I edit the card details manually it will include in the exported file. Any suggestions for include billing address in the export file?

```
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    payment_method: req.body.payment_method,
    email: req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    address: {
      line1: req.body.line1,
      line2: req.body.line2,
      city: req.body.city,
      state: req.body.state,
      postal_code: req.body.postal_code,
    },
    phone: req.body.phone,
    invoice_settings: {
      default_payment_method: req.body.payment_method
    },
  });
```

Comment: Are you expecting these details to be in the Customer, or the Payment Method?

Comment: @floatingLomas It would be better if I get these in customer object. But I could not find any report that has the address details. However the invoice has the address somehow.

Comment: I find the same problem today. The export of customers does not consistently include the address that I see in the dashboard for that customer.